How to Add a Payment Method Column to Settlement Report?
I'm working with the Settlement Report within the FBL Advance Report section in Magento 2. I need to add a column that displays
the payment method for each transaction. In the attached image, you can see the current columns in the report. I would like to add a new column for the payment method right after the last column (labeled "Status")

However, I only have access to MySQL and the Magento Admin Panel (no access to the full codebase or ability to modify files directly). Could someone guide me on how I can achieve this, possibly by making changes directly in the database or through the admin panel?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
